# How do I constrain in swift (Trailing Space to Container Margin)?

Tags: ios, layout, swift

**Background**

I am trying to anchor a CustomBadge (custom UIView) to the right margin programmatically, equivalent to Trailing Space to Container Margin in IB.

**Code**

```
badge = CustomBadge( string: String( badgeValue ), withStyle: badgeStyle )
badge!.frame  = frame
badge!.hidden = true

self.view.addSubview( badge! )

// badge!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints( false )

let trailingMargin = NSLayoutConstraint(item: badge!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
                toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.RightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0 )
view.addConstraint( trailingMargin )

let constY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: badge!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: StageIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0 )
view.addConstraint( constY )
```

The result shows a badge (red 25) that doesn't go to the margin!

[image]

**Other Trials**

Alternatively, if I comment out

```
badge!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints( false )
```

The badge just disappears.

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: You should have, badge!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false), and you shouldn't be setting any frames when you use auto layout. You probably need to give it a size as well as a position.

Comment: @rdelmar I tried uncommenting badge!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false), not setting frames, and calling badge!.autoBadgeSizeWithString( String( 25 )), but still no luck...

Comment: @rdelmar I take it back - you are 100% correct - if I explicitly call NSLayoutConstraint() with attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width and attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, it works great.  If you care to write a short answer, I can accept and then edit with code.  Thx!